# Efficient Image Export

Tags: graphics, performance-tuning, export, animation, video

I am trying to export around 10000 plots from Mathematica in order to compile them into an animation with another program. Using the following, where "frames" is the list of plots

```
Export["001.jpg", frames, "VideoFrames"]
```

works, but is exporting at a rate of about 1 frame per second. Is there a faster way to accomplish this? Thanks!

Comment: You could try to export into a lossless format. _Mathematica_'s image compression tools are not among the best. I am also not sure whether exporting all frames into a single file is a good idea with jpg format. _Maybe_ tiff works better. Should `frames` be a vector graphic, it might also be an option to export into a vector graphics format such as pdf or svg (the svg exporter tends to be a bit buggy, though) and to rasterize the images externally (e.g. with ffmpeg; it can rasterize at least svg; ffmpeg can merge the files into a single video).

Comment: However, vector graphics will be very slow for images with color gradients or with many polygons and lines. You may also try to `Rasterize` the images first which gives you a bit more of control. Make sure to be informed about the various options of `Rasterize` and `Export` (note that each export format may have its own extra options).

Comment: Since almost nothing is known about the actual plots, it is very hard to give a more precise answer.

Comment: Thanks so much!

Comment: You're welcome! Did it help?

Comment: Still running into some slow behavior with these options unfortunately, but faster than before!